# Test Class code coverage for Save() and Cancel() method in Controller?

Tags: visualforce, unit-test, controller, code-coverage

I am writing a test class for a controller and I am unable to get code coverage for save and cancel methods.

Controller Code:-

```
public with sharing class DamagedController {

    public Case cas{ get; set; }

    public DamagedController() {
        Id id = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
        cas = (id == null) ? new Case() :
        [SELECT Delivered__c,Type_of_Damage__c,Fault_station__c,Content_damaged__c,Contact_Name__c,Insurance__c,
         Mobile_Number__c,Temporary_Delivery_Address__c,Email__c,Alternative_Email__c,Permanent_Address__c,Temporary_Mobile_number__c,
         Flight_Details__c    ,Compensation_paid__c,Baggage_Color__c,Bag_routing__c,Bag_description__c,Bag_Brand_Name__c,
         Baggage_Tag__c,Total_Baggage_Weight__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :id];
             }

    public PageReference save() {
        try {
            upsert(cas);
        } catch(System.DMLException e) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(e);
            return null;
        }
        //  After successful Save, navigate to the default view page
        PageReference redirectSuccess = new ApexPages.StandardController(Cas).view();
        return (redirectSuccess);
    }
    public PageReference Cancel(){
        return null;
    }
}
```

and The Test class is

```
@isTest
private class DamagedController_Test{
    static testMethod void myUnitTest() {
        test.startTest();
        Case cas = new Case();
        cas.IsEscalated = false;
        cas.Category__c = 'International';
        cas.Mode__c = 'Integrated';
        cas.Permanent_Address__c = '43';
        cas.Mobile_no__c = '54343-95790'; 
        cas.Email__c = 'Email45@test.com'; 
        cas.Temporary_Delivery_Address__c = '46';
        cas.Colour_Type__c = 'Colou876';
        cas.Flight_Date__c = 'Fligh981';
        cas.Routing__c = 'Routi964';
        cas.Bag_Brand_Name__c = 'Bag_B634';
        cas.Bag_Last_Seen__c = 'Bag_L221';
        cas.Total_Bag_Weight__c = 57; 
        cas.Delivered__c = 58;
        cas.Missing_Baggage_Weight__c = 59;
        cas.Content_of_Bag__c = 'Conte549'; 
        cas.Remarks__c = 'Remar144'; 
        cas.Type_of_Damage__c = 'Type_104';
        cas.Fault_station__c = 'Fault597'; 
        cas.Content_damaged__c = 'Conte699';
        cas.Insurance__c = 'Yes';
        cas.Alternative_Email__c = 'Email73@test.com';
        cas.Temporary_Mobile_number__c = '54343-86762'; 
        cas.Compensation_paid__c = 'Compe792'; 
        cas.Bag_description__c = 'Bag_d658';
        Upsert cas;
        PageReference testPage = new pagereference('/apex/VisualforcePage');
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put( 'id', cas.id );

        DamagedController MyControllerObj = new DamagedController();
        PageReference pageref = MyControllerObj.save();

        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

Comment: This test case should produce partial coverage for `save()` and no coverage for `cancel()`, because you don't call it. Are you struggling to cover a specific code path? Also, you really need to add some assertions to show your code's behavior is correct.

Comment: Hi David Thanks for responding iam a newbie need your help,yes Iam getting patial coverage for save and no coverage for cancel ,can you please help me with my test class Pleeeease

Comment: Not a proper answer, but some general testing advice to help you on your way. **The golden rule of unit testing** is _you only gain coverage for code that is executed as part of a test method_. If you don't _call_ your `cancel()` method, it won't be executed. **The most important part of unit testing** is validating code behavior by making _assertions_ (i.e. `System.assertEquals(<expected value>, <actual value>, <fail message>);`). You can (and I would argue that you should) have more than one test method. Testing only one thing per test method makes it easier to figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @ManojNMurthy, I think it would be really useful if you could think through Derek's excellent advice, take a few minutes to read through the [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) section of the help center to get a better sense of what we *can* help you with and what details we need, and come back to make some edits to your question.

Comment: *Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is **the most important part of unit testing**. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as **[smoke tests](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_testing#Smoke_testing_in_software_development), which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests**.* - [How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)

Comment: Deleting your old questions and re-asking them in new posts is categorized as abusive behavior here and tends to get one banned (as it has already in your case). In the future, if you are able to dig your way out of this ban, please do not delete your posts, but rather edit them to try to improve their content and adherence to the guidelines in the [help].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now that I've gone over the basic testing advice in the comments, I'll take a crack at diagnosing the issues.

#### First off, the easy one.

Like I said in my comment, you aren't getting any coverage for your `cancel()` method because you aren't calling your `cancel()` method in any test. I'd recommend creating a separate test method for this. When you do, *don't forget about making assertions*. There isn't much in this method that you can assert against, but there is one thing...the return value.

If you aren't sure of *what* you should make assertions for, a general rule is if the code you are testing makes a change to a variable, an SObject field, or has a return type other than `void`, you want to assert that the variable, SObject field, or return type that results from you running your code was set to what you think it should be.

In your `save()` method, one assertion you could make is that if you did not pass an Id in your test url, that you end up being able to query one more `Case` after running the `save()` method than you could query before running the `save()` method.

For your `cancel()` method, like I said, you can assert that you actually do return null. Something like

```
Pagereference result = myController.cancel();
System.assertEquals(null, result, 'expected the pagereference returned by the cancel method to be null');
```

#### Now, the `save()` test

The first thing I see when you say you're having trouble with coverage for this method is your try/catch block.

You haven't indicated to us which lines are and are not covered, but if I were a betting man, I'd bet your coverage looks like this

```java
     // I'll use '/*+*/' at the start of a line to indicate a covered line
     public PageReference save() {
/*+*/    try {
/*+*/        upsert(cas);
/*+*/    } catch(System.DMLException e) {
/*+*/        ApexPages.addMessages(e);
/*+*/        return null;
/*+*/    }
         //  After successful Save, navigate to the default view page
         PageReference redirectSuccess = new ApexPages.StandardController(Cas).view();
         return (redirectSuccess);
     }
```

Catching an exception will consume that exception (unless you re-throw it). If you catch an exception, but don't do anything in your catch block, then *you're effectively sweeping the issue under the rug* (e.g. hiding the error and pretending it didn't happen). This makes for some tough debugging, especially after about 6 months or so when you start to forget what you did in a particular piece of code (or at least *why* you did what you did).

In this case, you are doing *something* with the exception (adding it to the page messages), but your test method is not making any assertions to see whether or not you encountered an exception (and added a page message).

#### Conclusion

You aren't getting full coverage for your `save()` method because you are running into an exception when you try to `upsert cas;`

We don't know what this error is because you are consuming the exception *and don't have an assertion to verify that you have 0 page messages, and print the page messages if there are more than 0.* This is a big part of why making assertions is so important.

With the current information you've provided us, we can't pinpoint the issue. By virtue of the `upsert` succeeding in the setup that you're doing in your test method, we can narrow things down to an issue with your constructor...but that's it.

Going forward, I would suggest creating a `String exceptionMessage;` in your controller, and setting this variable when you catch your exception. This will make it easier to surface the error that's happening in your test, which in turn will make it easier to figure out what exactly is wrong (and how to fix your test or controller).

The assertion that you could make after adding this variable could look like

```
System.assertEquals(0, ApexPages.getMessages().size(), 'Expected there to be no page messages. Added page message ' + myController.exceptionMessage);
```